# How to calculate Euclidian of dictionary with tuple as key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have created a matrix by using a dictionary with a tuple as the key (e.g. {(user, place) : 1 } )

I need to calculate the Euclidian for each place in the matrix. 
I've created a method to do this, but it is extremely inefficient because it iterates through the entire matrix for each place.

```
 def calculateEuclidian(self, place):
        count = 0;
        for key, value in self.matrix.items():
            if(key[1] == place and value == 1):
                count += 1
        euclidian = math.sqrt(count)
        return euclidian
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?
I need the result to be in a dictionary with the place as a key, and the euclidian as the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *dictionary comprehension* (using a vectorized form is much faster than a for loop) and accumulate the result of the conditionals (0 or 1) as the euclidean value:

```
def calculateEuclidian(self, place):
    return {place: sum(p==place and val==1 for (_,p), val in self.matrix.items())}
```

With your current data structure, I doubt there is any way you can avoid iterating through the entire dictionary.

Comment: that doesn't change the complexity, only makes it a tad faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use another way (or an auxiliary way) of representing your data, iterating through every element of the `dict` is as efficient as you can get (asymptotically), since there is no way to ask a `dict` with `tuple` keys to give you all elements with keys matching `(_, place)` (where `_` denotes "any value"). There are other, and more succinct, ways of writing the iteration code, but you cannot escape the asymptotic efficiency limitation.

If this is your most common operation, and you can in fact use another way of representing your data, you can use a `dict[Place, list[User]]` instead. That way, you can, in O(1) time, get the list of all users at a certain place, and all you would need to do is count the items in the list using the `len(...)` function which is also O(1). Obviously, you'll still need to take the `sqrt` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to create a new dictionary from your current dictionary which isn't adapted to this kind of search and create a dictionary with `place` as key and list of `(user,value)` tuples as values.

Get the tuple list under `place` key (that'll be fast), then count the times where `value` is 1 (linear, but on a small set of data)

Keep the original dictionary for euclidian distance computation. Hoping that you don't change the data too often in the program, because you'd need to keep both dicts in-sync.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but when need to compute the euclidean dist. based on a user later on?

Comment: I think you have to keep both dictionaries active. Hoping that they don't get updated too often because that would mean keeping them in-sync.

Answer (score 1):

There may be ways to make it more Pythonic, but I do not think you can change the overall complexity since you are making a query based off both key and value. I think you have to search the whole matrix for your instances.